# Memory Leak in Loop - C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

My program is leaking. At low-level code, I am using all the tools that [Julius](http://julius.osdn.jp/en_index.php) provides do free the memory. But I want to be sure that is my problem and not from the code. So this code will naturally leaking? (Multiple recognitions in loop, with the same pointer).

```
SREngineJulius *julius_pointer;
int iter = 10; //some number

    for(int i = 0; i <= iter; i++){

        julius_pointer= new SREngineJulius();
        julius_pointer->InitSREngine(jconf);
        julius_pointer->Callbacks();
        julius_pointer->DynamicAddCommands(palavras2,"|",0);
        buffering = julius_pointer->Audio_Buffering(audio_buffer, maxlen, 0,1);
        result = julius_pointer->NotifyCallbackLoop("nao_interessa_nada");
        julius_pointer->~SREngineJulius();
        delete julius_pointer;
}
```

Comment: Why on Earth are you calling the destructor manually?

Comment: Doin't call the destructor, `delete` does that for you

Comment: If you just create and then delete the objects in each iteration, you don't seem need dynamic memory at all!

Comment: @Angew To call the routines that will free the memory. Routines in the Julius Core. Should I use this routines outside of destructor?

Comment: @crashmstr this is just to simulate in offline mode, of the behavior in a server.

Comment: If it has routines for titying up memory, call them and THEN call ´delete'  only.

Comment: @carduh *never* call the destructor manually. It will be called when you use `delete`. If you call it manually, you're just asking for a double free or corruption error.

Comment: By the "methods of Julius to free the memory", you just mean `~SREEngineJulius()`, right? That's a special function called the destructor. The compiler will generate this call for you anyway when you `delete` the pointer, and you shouldn't call it directly.

Comment: @PCLuddite Am I doing a double free? So this could be the cause of the leaking?

Comment: @PCLuddite Ok, at this point the destructor has that methods. I did not know that the delete will cause a second call of the destructor. Thanks

Comment: In the nicest possible way, if you didn't know that, then it might be helpful to read a good book or find some other way to learn C++. This is very basic knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need dynamic allocation of the engine. Just use it as a local variable:

```
int iter = 10; //some number

for(int i = 0; i <= iter; i++){

        SREngineJulius julius_engine;
        julius_engine.InitSREngine(jconf);
        julius_engine.Callbacks();
        julius_engine.DynamicAddCommands(palavras2,"|",0);
        buffering = julius_engine.Audio_Buffering(audio_buffer, maxlen, 0,1);
        result = julius_engine.NotifyCallbackLoop("nao_interessa_nada");

        // SREngineJulius destructor is called automatically when the variable julius_engine goes out of scope in each iteration

}
```

If you still have memory leaks after these changes, then the leak is inside one of the SREngineJulius methods that are called inside the loop.